# setattribute label text value - PHP

Tags: php

I print the `title = "Damat Adi"` data on the screen in the lab. So, as you can see in the html tag, I print text on the screen. I am doing this in the code below. I want to update the text in this tag. So I want to do setattribute operation. So I want to update the `texttexttext` section.

**HTML**

```
<label class="example ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="2"  title="Damat Adi">texttexttext</label>
```

**PHP**

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

    $paketKFIYAT = $row['html_kod'];
    $classname = 'Damat Adi';
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($paketKFIYAT);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $results = $xpath->query("//*[@title='" . $classname . "']");

    if ($results->length > 0) {
        $review = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
        echo($review);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific, I can't understand what is your issue and what you need help with

Comment: If you want to change the content that you `echo` out, then just assign it using something like `$results->item(0)->nodeValue = "something new";`

Comment: I have to add it back into the html tag. @NigelRen

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: I want it to be this way after changing it. "<label class="example ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="2"  title="Damat Adi">something new</label>"